# React version of jQuery.getJSON {

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

New to **React** and trying to rebuild my site to ReactJS and GatsbyJS. One issue I keep coming up against is `getJSON`, especially in this code here.

How can I use this in React without needing jQuery?

```
_fetchWeather() {
  jQuery.getJSON({
    method: 'GET',
    data: {
      q: `select * from weather.forecast 
          where woeid in (select woeid from geo.places(1) 
          where text="${this.state.search}")`,
      format: 'json',
      env: 'store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys'
    },
    url: 'https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql'
  }).success(res => {
    this.setState({weather: res.query.results.channel});
  });
}
```

Comment: Same way as you make any other HTTP request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several options to get data from an API endpoint in React. The simplest is to use the [fetch api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) found in most modern browsers. If you are worried about compatibility issues, there are libraries such as [superaget](https://visionmedia.github.io/superagent/) and [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) both of which heavily leverage JavaScript's [promise api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)